# bootstrap table and jsf

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jsf

i trying to use bootstrap table libary with jsf but it's not working for me.

I have a facelet template where i included this files:

```
 <h:outputStylesheet name="./css/bootstrap-datepicker.css"/>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="./css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="./css/bootstrap-table.css"/>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="./css/sb-admin.css"/>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="./css/morris.css"/>

    <h:outputStylesheet name="./css/AdminLTE.css"/>
    <h:outputScript name="jquery/jquery-plugins.js" library="primefaces"/>
    <h:outputScript name="./js/jquery.js"></h:outputScript>
    <h:outputScript name="./js/addrow.js"></h:outputScript>
    <h:outputScript name="./js/modal.js"></h:outputScript>
    <h:outputScript name="./js/bootstrap.js"></h:outputScript>
    <h:outputScript name="./js/app.js"></h:outputScript>
    <h:outputScript name="./js/dashboard.js"></h:outputScript>
    <h:outputScript name="./js/demo.js"></h:outputScript>
    <h:outputScript name="./js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></h:outputScript>
    <h:outputScript name="./js/flot-data.js"></h:outputScript>
    <h:outputScript name="./js/bootstrap-table-all.js"></h:outputScript>
    <h:outputScript name="./js/raphael.min.js"></h:outputScript>
    <h:outputScript name="./js/morris.js"></h:outputScript>
    <h:outputScript name="./js/formatter.js"></h:outputScript>
    <h:outputScript name="./js/jquery.formatter.js"></h:outputScript>
```

I create a xhtml file whic is a client for this template..
The default bootstrap working fine in every client, i can use every class in bootstrap.css

But when I'm try to create a table in the client xhtml like this:

```
<table id="tsttable"  class="table table-bordered table-hover" >

<tr>
<th>Azonosító</th>
<th>Albetét típusa</th>
<th>Utca neve</th>
<th>Költségviselő neve</th>
</tr>

<tbody class="searchable">

<ui:repeat var="pack" value="#  {mainViewController.showPackageContent()}" varStatus="status">

<tr>
<td>
<h:commandLink  class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" value="#{pack.id}"  actionListener="#{mainViewController.navigateToChosedCustomer(item.id)}">

</h:commandLink>
</td>

<td>#{pack.types.description}</td>

<td>#{pack.BFlatDataCollection.addrStreet}</td>

<td>#{pack.BAssocCaseCollection.userId.lastName}
           #{pack.BAssocCaseCollection.userId.firstName}
</td>

</tr>
</ui:repeat>

</tbody>

</table>
```

And then if i add this "data-toggle="table" attribute to the table it doesn't have any effect..

But if i try to create a table in the client xhtml with js like this, the code create the bootstrap table:

```
$('#tsttable').bootstrapTable({
 columns: [{
 field: 'id',
 title: 'Item ID'
 }, {
 field: 'name',
 title: 'Item Name'
 }]});
```

How can i use bootstrap table with jsf? Does anybody has any idea? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Jsf is in this regard nothing more than a server side html generator. If you can do it in plain html (without the `$('#tsttable').bootstrapTable({...})`), you can do it in jsf to. So figuring that out will make the example above automagically work. But figuring this out should be a different question

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It does…  since the question is very specifically jsf targetted and jsf in fact, as I state, does not play any role in this not working.

Comment: You are right - JSF is not necessarily causing the issues. Nevertheless, that is not answering the question / providing a solution to his problem...

Comment: I know, but if there is a more generic cause of this not working, it is better made into a generic question. Otherwise the php, jsp, python, users will post similar questions because they skip this one due to the fact is is tagged jsf and not php or whatever.

Comment: I am totally with you regarding those arguments - but that still is no answer but should have been a comment imho ;-) It still stays a request to the OP to ammend his question. I never said you where wrong with what you said - I just flagged it as "not an answer" - which is what you agreed with in your last comment.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a native English speaker, but with _"I know"_ I meant I understand/hear what you say, (but not necessarily agree). And instead of_"It is better made into..."_ I should have said _"A new generic question should be created"_ But if you have a good suggestion what a better answer would look like without 'violating' the statements above, feel free to enlighten me. Always happy/eager/willing to learn